# Scala implicit conversion of apply method

Tags: scala, apply, implicit

I tried the following to create an option-checking style in code:

```
object Test {
  trait Check
  object x extends Check
  def option() = false
  def option(xx: Check) = true
  implicit class AugmentCheck(s: String) {
    def apply() = ""
    def apply(xx: Check) = s
  }
}
import Test._

val delete = option ( x )
val force  = option (   )

val res = "mystring" (   )
```

But I face the following problem:

```
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("mystring")
 required: ?{def apply: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method augmentString in object Predef of type (x: String)scala.collection.
immutable.StringOps
 and method AugmentCheck in object Test of type (s: String)Test.AugmentCheck
 are possible conversion functions from String("mystring") to ?{def apply: ?}
           val res = "mystring" (   )
                     ^
<console>:11: error: String("mystring") does not take parameters
           val res = "mystring" (   )
```

This is unfortunate, because even if there is ambiguity in the symbol name, there shouldn't be any ambiguity in the function signature.

If I introduce the method "apply", it works fine when there is an argument, but not without:

```
           val res = "mystring" apply ( x )

           res == ""
```

How can I remove the keyword "apply" in this case?

Comment: I get the same "ambiguous conversion" error even with your example that you say "works fine." I'm using Scala 2.10.3.

Comment: It works only when there is an argument. See update. Thank you for reporting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of representing the *on* and *off* states with `x` or  , what about using `y` for *yes* and `n` for *no*?

```
object Test {
  val y = true
  val n = false
  class DefaultConfigValue[U](val v: U)
  implicit class ConfigValue[U](v: U) {
    def y = v
    def n(implicit default: DefaultConfigValue[U]) = default.v
  }
  implicit val defaultConfigString = new DefaultConfigValue("")
}

import Test._
import language.postfixOps

val delete = y
val force  = n

val res1 = "my first string"   y
val res2 = "my second string"  n
```

Notice how you can import `postfixOps` and then just add extra whitespace to align all the `y`s and `n`s for your string configuration options into the same column.

I'm not sure if this makes sense, but I wrote the above code such that you should be able to use any type (not just strings) for the options with the `y` and `n` postfix operators. All you have to do to enable a new type is create an implicit `DefaultConfigValue` for that type so that the *no* option has something to return.

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend against using this pattern, as it violates the principle of least surprise.

`StringOps` already defines `apply(n)` on a `String` to return the Nth character, any other overload is going to confuse a lot of people. Even in the context of a DSL.

`Option` is also a well-understood term, whose meaning is overloaded here.

Finally: `x` is very commonly used as a parameter to methods and as a bound value in pattern-matching.  Using it in a wide scope like this is going to cause a lot of shadowing, and risks causing some very unexpected error messages.

Can you give a better idea of what you're trying to achieve so that we can suggest some better alternatives?

Comment: I would like to be able to modify certain options in the code by adding or removing a character in a place such that this appears to be like a checking box.